# angularjs named ui-views updating just one ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8 and the ui-router and I have a menu on the left and a content area on the right.

I want the ability to navigate through the menu system without updating the 'content' ui-view, is that possible?

In my index.html I have these two ui-views

```
  <div ui-view="menu"></div>
  <div class="content" ui-view="content"></div>
```

Then in my settings route file I have the following;

```
settingsRoute = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            views: {
                "menu": {templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html'}
            }
        })
        .state('account', {
            url: "/account",
            views: {
                "menu": {templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html'},
                "content": {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
                    controller: 'account'
                }
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/account');
}
```

In my costings route file I have

```
costingsRoute = function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('costings', {
            url: '/costings',
            views: {
                "menu": {templateUrl: 'templates/costings.html'}
            }
        })
        .state('invoices', {
            url: '/invoices',
            views: {
                "menu": {templateUrl: 'templates/costings.html'},
                "content": {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/invoices.html'
                }
            }
        })
}

angular.module('app').config(costingsRoute);
```

For example in the following demo when it loads it loads with the account body displayed in the content, when I click on 'costings' I would like that to only change the menu and leave the content view with whatever is in the content view, this could be 'account body' or 'profile body'.

https://plnkr.co/f7A773GJdu3NWy3Lg2eK

Answer (score 0):

add this to your costing view...

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q2nXXWpSywkdEUKIUmC0?p=preview

```
.state('costings', {
            url: '/costings',
            views: {
                "menu": {templateUrl: 'costings.html'},
                "content": {
                    templateUrl: 'account.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I would like it to remember which page I'm on. So if I have another page there like profile and I'm on the profile page and I switch to the costings menu then it should keep displaying the profile page.